# reactstrap not displaying the selected default value/value within the dropdown list

Tags: reactjs, select, reactstrap

By clicking a button a have to set the default value/value into the dropdown list.

I am not able to display the selected value inside the option dropdown, I tried with both state and hardcoded defaultValue/value but the dropdown still renders the list as it is from parent component

Here a codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-borg-99bic?file=/src/App.js:3419-3912

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Select` component is accepting default value/value in following format
`id/type`.

So you need to change the way you are storing selected value in `handleClick` function like below:-

```
setSelectedValue(`${removedUndefined[0].id}/${removedUndefined[0].type}`);
```

Comment: i accepted your answer because is working but can you please elaborate it a bit more? thanks a lot

Comment: In select component, we should always pass same value as we are passing in it's options so if we pass different value then select will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your handleSelect function, you should add

`setSelectedValue(value);`

Comment: I tried with no success, in the handleselect is actually correctly selecting when selecting from the list but i would like to put the selected one when i click the button